# Mac mic not working in FaceTime only

Tags: mac, facetime, microphone

I have an M1 Mac Mini running Monterey 12.6. I have external bluetooth and USB mics hooked up. These mics work fine in quicktime, system preferences, zoom, and all other apps, but they do not work in FaceTime.

I can select the different microphones, but during a call, the soundwave indicator is flat and the people on the other end hear silence. Facetime is not switched to "mute".

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does changing settings in menu bar Video > Microphone make any difference. There are "Use system settings", "USB PnP Audio Device" etc options

Comment: @AivarPaalberg no. As I said, I can select any microphone and every one of them is silent.